# i want to have different result for datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm using sql server and I want my [check out] column to have a different datetime than in the [check in] column. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```sql
CREATE TABLE [Contract]
(
    RoomID CHAR(4) 
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.ROOM(RoomID) CHECK(RoomID LIKE '[A-F][1-5][0-9][0-9]' OR RoomID LIKE '[A-F][1-5][0-9][0-9]'),
    CustomerID VARCHAR(7) 
    FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.customer(CustomerID) CHECK(CustomerID LIKE 'SE[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR CustomerID LIKE 'SB[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' OR CustomerID LIKE 'HE[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL,
    [Check-in] DATETIME 
    CHECK([Check-in] <= GETDATE()) NOT NULL,
    [Check-out] DATETIME 
)
```

Comment: You should NOT have a check constraint on RoomID as it is a foreign key to another table. That check constraint should be defined on the column in dbo.ROOM (if it is needed). That constraint also contains redundant expressions. Same thought also applies to CustomerID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.Contraint ADD CONSTRAINT chk_CheckInCheckOut CHECK ([Check-out] IS NULL OR [Check-out] != [Check-in])
```

Side note, I really suggest *not* using object names that require delimit identification. A hyphen (`-`) shouldn't be in an object's name. Snake_case/CamelCase are far better options.